# Easy Custom Labeling plugin does allow to save?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I use the **Easy Custom Labeling plugin** chose positions of the labels and safe the layer and project for continuing later. When opening again the project, the layer opens but without any objects inside. Is there a reason why the layer is saved, but not its content?

Comment: I am not sure about Easy Custom Labeling, but check the source of the layer. It sounds like it is putting them in a temporary file that needs to be saved before exiting, or you need to save the edits on the layer before exiting.

Comment: Yes it must be a temporary file. If I save it as a shape-file and import the new shape-file it works! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, does that fix everything you need? If so I will submit it as an actual answer.

Comment: Yes it is :) Go ahead it's yours!

Answer (score 4):

If you are working a lot with the Easy Custom Labeling plugin, I recommend you to install the **Memory layer saver** plugin. Thus, you no longer have to save the labels in a shapefile and you can easily go on in your labeling process later on. But do not forget to leave the edit session of the layer before you save your project!

Answer (score 2):

Check the source of the layer. It sounds like it is putting them in a temporary file that needs to be saved before exiting, or you need to save the edits on the layer before exiting.

Comment: But just saving the layer before exiting does not help. You need to save it as a new shape-file and import is as a new layer.